# Remove the Reject mention

Tags: support

Remove "reject" in [this suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/902895)

I just wanted to add extra information, that if the keys for addition division etc. are to be used, the right Unicode has to be chosen

Comment: ^^Assuming so, I have rolled back the edit. If it's not what you want, you can edit your answer again.

Comment: I don't understand your question / request. Can you please clarify? Did you reject the suggestion by accident? What do you mean about wanting to add information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for us to retroactively edit the 'feedback' given on a suggested edit, therefore we cannot remove it.

The only way for this to happen would be someone going in at the database level to remove it, and that'd only be SE employees who can do that, and I don't think they'd be willing to do that just to remove a single 'reject' feedback, whether legitimately a reject or not.